# How does the tomcat servlet container know if authentication succeeds?

Tags: java, authentication, security, tomcat, jaas

I am failing to create custom login modules because I don't understand how the tomcat servlet container works. I have a web.xml with security-constraints, auth-constraints, url-patterns, etc. When I specify org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule in my jaas.conf, login works as expected. When I specify my bare bones custom login module, authentication does not succeed. Here is an example:

```
@Override
public boolean commit() {
    subject.getPrincipals().add(new CustomPrincipal("admin"));
    subject.getPrincipals().add(new CustomPrincipal("users"));
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean login() throws LoginException {
    return true;
}
```

These methods are called, but login fails. How does the servlet container know if authentication succeeds? I thought it would check to make sure commit returns true and any principal exists. I added "users" because that is the auth-constraint specified in web.xml protecting the resources.

Comment: Hi. How do you know they are called? To confirm everything is wired up correctly you could add some logging above both methods just to print out something to the screen. Also when you say "authentication does not succeed" are you saying it re-prompts for password or you get a specific error?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil I know they are called because I have logging in the methods. I get re-prompted for the username and password with an error that the credentials are wrong. Additionally, I have an unsecure endpoint I call to print out a host of information including getUserPrincipal which is null. I believe I need to get tomcat to return something for getUserPrincipal but I don't know how.

Comment: Which interface are you overriding for your "bare bones" implementation? If its the LoginModule interface I dont see you overriding initialize()

Comment: Yes, it is LoginModule. I override initialize, but it only calls super. I haven't paid much attention to that method.

Comment: It sound like your also inheriting another class not just implementing the LoginModule interface (which has no super if you're talking about javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule) Could you post the full class or at least enough to show your calls to extends, implements and all the overrides?

Comment: Your questions have helped me discover that the CustomPrincipal I am using seems to be the issue. If I change that to SimplePrincipal from the jboss library, I am able to set the user principal. I haven't figured out why yet, but I appreciate the help!